# Which build-in exception to subclass for "give up on this one"

Tags: python

I have this high-level code:

```
class SkipThisRow( RuntimeError): pass
...

for row in reader:
    try:
        process_row( row)
    except SkipThisRow:
        print("Giving up on row {}".format( reader.line_num ) )
```

It feels "wrong" subclassing `RuntimeError` (or `Exception`) for something which is a normal and expected part of the program's operation. The exception being handled is raised because the data on a particular row (of a csv file) is too complex for this program to handle. (A detailed description of the problem whas been output by the lower-level code).

Is there a built-in exception to subclass for exceptions which aren't errors, but rather a convenient way of handling the program flow (an easy exit from many levels of block structure and function call)?

(If there's nothing built-in I guess I should define `class FlowControl( Exception)` and then `class SkipThisRow( FlowControl)` )

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from `Exception` is not a problem for a "normal" flow control exception.
Look at the [Python builtin exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html?highlight=exceptions#exception-hierarchy), the `StopIteration` exception is a direct subclass of `Exception`.

You obviously are free to design an exceptions tree, and it is not a bad pratice, but it is not mandatory.